# Wordpress - content (text) not showing up

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code which I am trying to pull out just the text from my wordpress post and be able to echo just the text content in a div. (I am removing the blockquotes, images, etc from the post to be used elsewhere)

```
    <?php
    $content = get_the_content();
    $content = wpautop($content);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML(get_the_content(), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    foreach ($xpath->query('//blockquote') as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }

    foreach ($xpath->query('//img') as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }

    foreach( $xpath->query('//p[not(node())]') as $node ) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }

    $content = $doc->saveHTML($doc);            
    ?>  

<div>               
    <?php echo $content ?>  
</div>
```

however the content doesn't appear.

Comment: You have to used the strip_tag to remove the html tag from the content .


http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overdoing too much for just retrieving a post. Why not just use the_content(); inside the loop?

get_the_content() does not auto-embed videos, or expand shortcodes, among other things -- and I can see that you are loading it again to an HTML format

Comment: I want to remove all the images and blockquotes that are in the posts aswell

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
 use the_content();
```

Comment: in what way, in the php tags <?php use the_content(); ?>